# Python Find Tuple by Geographic Priority

Tags: python, beginner

Requirement:

> Python Function will read a LIST of TUPLES. The structure of the tuple is ("STRING", "STRING","STRING",INT,"GEOGRAPHIC VALUE")
>
> This Geographic value can have 5 values "zip", "city", "county", "state" and "country"
>
> Now if a Tuple has elements where geographic values are (....,"zip"),(....,"county"), (....,"country") then function should return the element/tuple which contains "zip"
>
> Examples :
>
> Input : `[('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 1, 'state'), ('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 2, 'zip')]`
>
> Output : `['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 2, 'zip']`
>
> In other words 'zip' is higher priority(hp) than 'city'.
>
> 'city' is HP than 'county',
>
> 'county' is HP than 'state'
>
> and 'state' is HP than 'country'.

I have written code for that but being new to Python, the code looks clunky. Is there any shorter method?

```
def unique_list(input):
    my_list = input
    print(my_list)
    last_list = []
    zipcnt = -1
    citicnt = -1
    countycnt = -1
    statecnt = -1
    return_list_zip = []
    return_list_city = []
    return_list_county = []
    return_list_state = []
    return_list_country = []
    for j in range(len(my_list)):
          if(my_list[j][4]) == "zip":
             zipcnt = len(my_list)
             return_list_zip = list(my_list[j])
             continue
          elif (my_list[j][4] == 'city' and zipcnt == -1):
              citycnt = len(my_list)
              return_list_city = list(my_list[j])
              continue
              
          elif (my_list[j][4] == 'county' and zipcnt == -1 and citicnt == -1):
              countycnt = len(my_list)
              return_list_county = list(my_list[j])
              continue
          elif (my_list[j][4]  == 'state'and zipcnt == -1 and citicnt == -1 and countycnt == -1):
              statecnt = len(my_list)
              return_list_state = list(my_list[j])
              continue
          elif (my_list[j][4] == 'country'and zipcnt == -1 and citicnt == -1 and countycnt == -1 and statecnt == -1):
              return_list_country = list(my_list[j])
              continue
    if(zipcnt != -1):
        return_list = return_list_zip
    elif(citycnt != -1):
        return_list = return_list_city
    elif(countycnt != -1):
        return_list = return_list_county
    elif (statecnt != -1):
        return_list = return_list_state
    else:
        return_list = return_list_country
    return return_list
input_list = [ ("aa", "bb", "cc", 1,"state"), ("aa","bb","cc",2,"zip")]
input_list1 = [("XX","YY","NN",1,"country"),("XX","YY","NN",2,"city"),  ("XX","YY","NN",3,"state")]
input_list2 = [("NN","FF","PP",10,"state"),("NN","FF","PP",11,"country"),("NN","FF","PP",10,"city")]
print(unique_list(input_list))
print(unique_list(input_list1))
print(unique_list(input_list2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, it is clunky.

The first important step is to pick a function name that succinctly describes the task that it performs, namely, picking the most specific address component.

Once you do that, you might realize that "the most *X* of *Y*" means that you should use the [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function.  You just have to map each tuple to some quantitative measure of "specificity".

```
def most_specific_address(addresses):
    SPECIFICITY = {
        'country': 1, 'state': 2, 'county': 3, 'city': 4, 'zip': 5,
    }
    return max(addresses, key=lambda addr: SPECIFICITY[addr[4]])
```

Comment: I read about using key = lambda using following link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296755/python-max-function-using-key-and-lambda-expression    Just one question:  What does Lamda return as 'key' is it the tuple having highest specificity ?

Comment: For any input tuple, the lambda maps it to a specificity level. Then the `max()` function returns the tuple whose specificity level is the greatest.